# Iterate and assign weights based on two columns (python)

Tags: python, pandas

| **FI_name** | ISN | Sector | Industry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REC | INE02 | PS | FS |
| HDB | INE03 | PR | FS |
| ABC | INE04 | PR | FS |
| RHC | INE05 | PR | CO |
| ZHE | INE06 | PR | FS |
| HSE | INE07 | PR | FS |
| ZAK | INE08 | PS | MT |
| HGB | INE09 | PR | FS |
| YUJ | INE10 | PR | MT |
| WSD | INE11 | PS | FS |
| REC | INE12 | PS | FS |
| HDB | INE13 | PR | FS |
| ABC | INE14 | PR | FS |
| RHC | INE15 | PR | CO |
| ZHE | INE16 | PR | FS |
| HSE | INE17 | PR | FS |
| ZAK | INE18 | PS | MT |
| HGB | INE19 | PR | FS |
| YUJ | INE20 | PR | MT |
| WSD | INE21 | PS | FS |

All the unique ISN should be assigned an equal weight (totals 100) but with the following exceptions.

1. Each unique Industry which has sector type "PR" is capped at 25%
2. So any ISN with sector 'PR' for their entire Industry should not cross the 25% limit.
3. If any industry has breached the 25% limit (i.e., if total number of ISNs in any industry is more than 5) then all those ISNs in that particular industry should be adjusted between the 25%
4. No limit for ISNs with sector == 'PS' (irrespective of the Industry)

the expected weights should be like this....

| **FI_name** | ISN | Sector | Industry | Weights |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REC | INE02 | PS | FS | 7.5% |
| HDB | INE03 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| ABC | INE04 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| RHC | INE05 | PR | CO | 7.5% |
| ZHE | INE06 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| HSE | INE07 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| ZAK | INE08 | PS | MT | 7.5% |
| HGB | INE09 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| YUJ | INE10 | PR | MT | 7.5% |
| WSD | INE11 | PS | FS | 7.5% |
| REC | INE12 | PS | FS | 7.5% |
| HDB | INE13 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| ABC | INE14 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| RHC | INE15 | PR | CO | 7.5% |
| ZHE | INE16 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| HSE | INE17 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| ZAK | INE18 | PS | MT | 7.5% |
| HGB | INE19 | PR | FS | 2.5% |
| YUJ | INE20 | PR | MT | 7.5% |
| WSD | INE21 | PS | FS | 7.5% |

There are total 10 ISNs with Sector == 'PR' and Industry == 'FS', so all these ISNs are assigned an equal weight of 2.5% (25%/10)
Since industries apart from FS (and sector 'PR') do not breach the limit of 25%, so 7.5% (75%/10) has been assigned for the rest.

**This is the current code but I believe there's a better approach. Is there any other approach to tackle the above condition? any shorter method?**

```
# Sector weight identification
import pandas as pd
sff1 = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\RajashekarR\Downloads\Test_CodeR.xlsx')

swi = sff1.loc[sff1['Sector'] != "PS"]
swi_pivot = swi.pivot_table(values=['ISN'], index = 'Industry', aggfunc= ['count'])
swi_pivot.columns = ['count',]
swi = pd.merge(swi, swi_pivot, how='inner', on='Industry')
swi2 = pd.merge(sff1, swi, how='left', left_on=['ISN', 'FI_name', 'Sector', 'Industry'], right_on=['ISN', 'FI_name', 'Sector', 'Industry'])


# Sector weight allocation
o = 20
l = 0.25
n = o*l
c= swi2['count']
n1 = c[c > n].count()
n2 = o-n1
swi3 = swi2.loc[swi2['count'] > n]
swi3['Weights'] = l/swi2['count']
s_sum = swi3['Weights'].sum()
l1 = 1-s_sum
swif = pd.merge(swi2, swi3, how='left', left_on=['ISN', 'FI_name', 'Sector', 'Industry', 'count'], right_on=['ISN', 'FI_name', 'Sector', 'Industry', 'count'])
swif = swif.set_index('ISN')
swi4 = swif[swif['Weights'].isna()]
swi4['Weights'] = l1/n2
swif = swif.reindex(columns=swif.columns.union(swi4.columns))
swif.update(swi4)
swif.reset_index(inplace=True)
final = swif.drop(['count'], axis=1)
final.to_excel('Test_CodeR_Final.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `pivot_table`, `reindex` and `merge` is in all cases unnecessary. I also find that you hold onto a lot of temporary values, none very well-named, when you can just reassign to older variables and allow Python to do cleanup based on dropped references.

Rather than `c[c > n].count()`, you can call `.sum()` directly on the boolean predicate.

There's probably more simplification possible, but the results from this pass match yours.

```py
import pandas as pd

sff1 = pd.read_csv('Weights - Sheet1.csv')

# Sector weight allocation
o = len(sff1)
l = 0.25
n = o*l

is_not_ps = sff1.Sector != "PS"
sff1.loc[is_not_ps, 'count'] = (
    sff1[is_not_ps]
    .groupby('Industry')
    .ISN.transform('count')
)

n1 = (sff1['count'] > n).sum()
n2 = o - n1

swi3 = sff1[sff1['count'] > n]
swi3['Weights'] = l/sff1['count']
l1 = 1 - swi3.Weights.sum()
sff1['Weights'] = swi3.Weights
sff1 = sff1.set_index('ISN')
swi4 = sff1[sff1.Weights.isna()]
swi4['Weights'] = l1 / n2
sff1.update(swi4)
final = sff1.drop(['count'], axis=1)
```